# disable a network interface on booting ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, linux-networking

I use **ubuntu 12.04**. I need to boot with one of the network interfaces **'eth1' down**. I tried adding

> sudo ifconfig eth1 down

to  */etc/rc.local*  However it seems the interface is brought up and then down. Is there any way it should not start on boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the interfaces that should not come up on boot on a new file 
`/etc/network/interfaces.noboot`, then bring them up when needed with:

```
sudo ifup -i /etc/network/interfaces.noboot -v eth1
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to remove the relevant entries from the `/etc/network/interfaces` file  but check out it's associated documentation [interfaces(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/interfaces.5.html) to be sure.

Comment: If I remove the entries from interfaces file, what could be the easy method to bring up and add/remove  a static IP to this interface?